# How to search Folder with luceneSearch in Alfresco

Tags: directory, alfresco

I have tried to search a folder with a Lucene search script, but my link doesn't work, can someone help me please, this is my code.

```
var folderNode =  search.luceneSearch(PATH:"/app:company_home/* " AND +@cm\:name:args.folderName AND TYPE:"cm:folder"); //don't work

if(folderNode.length == 1){

    folderNode[0].setPermission("Contributor", "admin");
    folderNode[0].setPermission("Contributor", "Developpers");
    model.myStatus = "Permission was set successfully!";

} else  if (folderNode.length == 0){

    model.myStatus = "Folder not found";

} else {

    model.myStatus = "Duplicate folder found";

}
```

Comment: where you have created this script in alfresco or in share?

Comment: I create this script in web script folder
I have create two pther file exactly in this link 
https://anythingalfresco.wordpress.com/tag/search-lucenesearch/

Comment: I found my error, i forgot .get in my .js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
var folderNode =  search.luceneSearch("PATH:\"/app:company_home/cm:**HereYourFolderName**\" AND TYPE:\"cm:folder\"");
```

And make sure you have created this web-script in alfresco.